# Top 10 status is within reach!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, praise

[image: GD site stats screenshot 15-02-2015]

Graphic Design, the 38th oldest site on the network is currently:

### Ranking 18th overall on traffic generated each day!

- 39th overall on number of total questions
- 36th on questions per day
- 28th on number of users

Every single other statistic available there is below 18th. Believe it or not, that's very positive!

It means we have **lots of potential**. It means that when the other stats increase, the views per day should increase fairly proportionately. Theoretically, if we doubled the number of total questions, number of questions per day, and the number of users, the traffic should increase by around double.

That's very inaccurate in reality though. There are other factors to account for, the most notable one being quality. We must maintain the same quality of content during the increase to have a shot at doubling the views per day. Disregarding quality would probably make views go down in the long term.

### So, what's my point?

#### We've actually gotten this far without making a plan to promote our site.

I am aware there were some initiatives to increase activity before I joined, which I think were efforts by the SE team to kickstart GD. We've never had a community promotion plan that I know of.

If we've gained this many views without consciously trying to increase them, imagine what we could do with a with a clear cut plan and some well-focused effort!

I actually think there's enough potential here for top 5 status, but let's not get ahead of ourselves.

---

### What can we do to increase activity?

This question is what I want everybody to give their input on. The ideas I've come up with for promoting the site are:

**1. Post an inviting comment and a link on the vast array of social networks.**

> Look for groups, pages, and people that talk about graphic design related topics. Facebook is full of such groups, Twitter is full of self-promoting, tutorial-writing freelancers. LinkedIn has many GD related groups and freelancers, I've posted links there myself in the past. I'm fairly sure Google+ must have some relevant places to post links as well.

**2. Expand our inventory of tags.**

> Our previous efforts to improve all of the existing tags seemed to have an effect on our traffic. During the weeks after, I watched our views per day grow by over 10000. We'd also graduated not long before, which may have contributed. I often find that we don't have tags to cover some aspects of questions. I don't want to create them at the time because I'm not sure they're on topic, or can't think of a good word. If we expand the collection of relevant tags, and fill in their wikis and descriptions, it may contribute to more views.

**3. Post community created questions.**

> I can personally identify keywords through Google for questions we haven't covered. I don't feel comfortable posting and answering many simple questions like this though. What I propose is we suggest questions as a community, and ask new users that want to get involved to post them. I can identify relevant questions for topics such as:
>
> - Simple Adobe How To's (literally hundreds of simple questions we haven't covered that have SEO potential)
> - Learning specific areas of Graphic Design
> - Teaching Graphic Design (we haven't got many yet when there is a lot of potential in that area)
> - GIMP and Inkscape have so much more potential than we're currently utilising

#### Please suggest more ways to increase our rank for traffic, and any thoughts you have on this.

---

These are only basic ideas. If there is enough enthusiasm for any of them, I would like to create a separate Meta post to discuss the important details of each.

The ideal outcome of this, would be a new meta post where we set SMART objectives based on the ideas here.

Comment: Unfortunately, an official GD.SE blog is no longer in the cards. [This is why the blog never came to fruition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/216955).

Comment: That sucks. I've always thought we would benefit from it for a few purposes.

Comment: I think it is getting boring because we are closing and holding so many questions. beside that giving the impression that new users must be experts to ask new questions.

Comment: we just dont generate enough questions worth answering. Also new uers have problems understanding the scope of the site. Maybe the scope needs to be changed but we are not interested in that either.